# jQuery Optimization - Dry

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry, datedropper

I've this simple situation:

```
$("#check-in").dateDropper({
    years_multiple: "10",
    format: "d-m-Y",
    minYear: "2015",
    maxYear: "2016",
    lang: "pt",
    animation: "bounce",
    placeholder: "Dia da entrada."
});

$("#check-out").dateDropper({
    years_multiple: "10",
    format: "d-m-Y",
    minYear: "2015",
    maxYear: "2016",
    lang: "pt",
    animation: "bounce",
    placeholder: "Dia da saída."
});
```

The only difference is placeholder: "...".

How can I optimize this code to not be repetitive (DRY)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#check-in,#check-out").each(function(){
    var daylabel = this.id==="check-in" ? "entrada" : "saida";
    $(this).dateDropper({
        years_multiple: "10",
        format: "d-m-Y",
        minYear: "2015",
        maxYear: "2016",
        lang: "pt",
        animation: "bounce",
        placeholder: "Dia da "+daylabel+"."
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#check-in, #check-out").dateDropper({
    years_multiple: "10",
    format: "d-m-Y",
    minYear: "2015",
    maxYear: "2016",
    lang: "pt",
    animation: "bounce",
    placeholder:($(this).attr('id') == "check-in" ? "Dia da entrada." : "Dia da saída.")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :-

```
$("#check-in,#check-out").dateDropper({
    years_multiple: "10",
    format: "d-m-Y",
    minYear: "2015",
    maxYear: "2016",
    lang: "pt",
    animation: "bounce",
    placeholder: ($(this).attr('id') == "check-in" ? "Dia da entrada." : "Dia da saída.")
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kartikeya, but Dystroy has already solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#check-in,#check-out").dateDropper({
    years_multiple: "10",
    format: "d-m-Y",
    minYear: "2015",
    maxYear: "2016",
    lang: "pt",
    animation: "bounce",
    placeholder: "Dia da "+($(this).attr('id') == "check-in" ? "entrada." : "saída.")
});
```